# Trying to move a sprite in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I'm trying to make a bullet move in Pygame. Apologies if it has a simple fix, I just can't think at the moment.

This is what I run when I detect that the "1" button is pressed.

```
 if pygame.event.get().type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_1:
    bullet = Bullet()
    bullet.rect.x = player.rect.x
    bullet.rect.y = player.rect.y
    entities.add(bullet)
    bullet_list.add(bullet)
    bullet.update()
```

...and this is the actual bullet class. The spacing is a bit off.

```
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
         super(Bullet, self).__init__()
         self.image = pygame.Surface([4, 10])
         self.image.fill(pygame.Color(255, 255, 255))
         self.isMoving = False
         self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):
       for i in range(20):
          self.rect.x += 3
```

I understand that the update method is happening instantly rather than the slower movement I want. How am I supposed to make the bullet move slower?
All the answers that I've seen involve completely stopping the program instead of just stopping the one object. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update all bullets on every game tick, not just when a player presses a button.

So, you'll want something like this as your event loop:

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_1:
            bullet = Bullet()
            bullet.rect.x = player.rect.x
            bullet.rect.y = player.rect.y
            entities.add(bullet)
            bullet_list.add(bullet)
    for bullet in bullet_list:
        bullet.update()
```

And, modify the Bullet class to do incremental moves, like so:

```
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
         super(Bullet, self).__init__()
         self.image = pygame.Surface([4, 10])
         self.image.fill(pygame.Color(255, 255, 255))
         self.isMoving = False
         self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):
       self.rect.x += 3
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. I already had a clock.tick() in the program but I was putting the update in the button press, like you said I was. So if I understand correctly, just use clock to do any time events?

Comment: `clock.tick(60)` ensures that the loop executes no more often than 60 times per second. Each run through of that loop is called a Frame, a discrete state of the game. That's where the term Frames Per Second (FPS) comes from. They key is having a multitasking architecture, so that any one action doesn't stop everything else from happening. For example, if you're rendering an animation, you can't stop updating the image just because you want to capture user input. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_programming#Game_structure for some more info.